# Reading NFC tag not working with Arduino Uno + PN532 itead module

Tags: arduino, nfc, arduino-uno

I am struggling to read a NFC tag (and then write on it) with an Arduino Uno and a PN532 module. I use the itead PN532 NFC module (http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/ITEAD_PN532_NFC_MODULE) with my Arduino.
I want to use I2C communication. So I have linked my ports like that:

- IRQ (NFC module) to A2 (Arduino Uno)
- RST (NFC module) to A3 (Arduino Uno)
- SDA (NFC module) to A4 (Arduino Uno)
- SCL (NFC module) to A5 (Arduino Uno)
- GND (NFC module) to GND (Arduino Uno)
- 5V  (NFC module) to 5V (Arduino Uno)

Then I have linked my Arduino to my laptop using USB. I have downloaded the Adafruit_PN532_master library to use it with my shield. And then I have tried to read an NFC tag using this code but it is not working as it should.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>


// If using the breakout with SPI, define the pins for SPI communication.
#define PN532_SCK  (13)
#define PN532_MOSI (11)
#define PN532_SS   (10)
#define PN532_MISO (12)


#define PN532_IRQ   (2)
#define PN532_RESET (3)  // Not connected by default on the NFC Shield

Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_IRQ, PN532_RESET);
boolean val(true);

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello!");

  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); 
  }
  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);

  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();

  Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A Card ...");
}


void loop(void) {
  uint8_t success;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength ;  // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)

  // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
  // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
  // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], (uint8_t*) &uidLength);
  Serial.println(success);

  if (success) {
    // Display some basic information about the card
    Serial.println("Found an ISO14443A card");
    Serial.print("  UID Length: "); Serial.print(uidLength, DEC); Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("  UID Value: ");
    nfc.PrintHex(uid, uidLength);

    if (uidLength == 4)
    {
      // We probably have a Mifare Classic card ... 
      uint32_t cardid = uid[0];
      cardid <<= 8;
      cardid |= uid[1];
      cardid <<= 8;
      cardid |= uid[2];  
      cardid <<= 8;
      cardid |= uid[3]; 
      Serial.print("Seems to be a Mifare Classic card #");
      Serial.println(cardid);
    }
    Serial.println("");
    val = false;
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

As a result from Arduino monitor I have
*"Hello! Found chip PN532. Firmware ver. 1.6. Waiting for an ISO14443A Card..."* And nothing else. My NFC tag is over the shield so I don't understand why it can't read it. It seems like it detects the tag presence. But it can't read it. I feel there is something wrong in this function : readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0],&uidLength) but I don't figure why.

Even if I am running an example from the Adafruit_PN532 library it shows me the same output because it's not able to read the tag.

I might have missing something... If you have any idea, could you please help me?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The define at the top of your code don't show the same pin than the connected one.

for exemple the IRQ should be connected on the pin 2 not on the A2. try to match it with the code or change the code to make them match